# Why does Intellisense show '<unknown>' for a templated method?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, intellisense

My class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BST.h"
using namespace std;

template <class type>
class avlTree : public binarySearchTree<type>
{
public:
    avlTree();      //default constructor
    ~avlTree();     //destructor
    const type & findMin() const;
    const type & findMax() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void printTree() const;
    void makeEmpty();
    void insert(const type & newData);
    void remove(const type & deleteItem);

private:
    struct avlNode
    {
        type info;
        avlNode *left;
        avlNode *right;
        int height;

        avlNode(const type & data, avlNode *ll, avlNode *rl, int h = 0)
            : info{ data }, left{ ll }, right{ rl }, height{ h } {}
    };

    avlNode * root;

    void insert(const type & newData, avlNode * & p);
    void remove(const type & deleteItem, avlNode * & p);
    avlNode* findMin(avlNode * p);
    avlNode* findMax(avlNode * p);

};
```

Here's one of the definitions I'm having problems with:

```
template <class type>
typename avlTree<type>::avlNode* avlTree<type>::findMin(avlNode * p)
{
    if (p == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (p->left == nullptr)
        return p;
    return findMin(p->left);
}
```

Although I haven't tried running the program with actual data, it does build and compile with no errors. But when I try to access avlNode pointer `p`'s members (e.g. `p->member`) the Intellisense drop down menu doesn't show up. Additionally, when I hover the cursor on top of the `member` in `p->member` (or `left` in `p->left` in the above code), the little message Intellisense displays is `<unknown>avlTree<type>::avlNode::left`. So why can't I see the members? And what does the "unknown" mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you haven't run the program how will it know what type you're using? It's generic class.

Comment: @Aesthete My main concern is why I'm not seeing the drop down menu of the members when I use the arrow operator on the pointer. I'm assuming it's connected to why Intellisense is showing that <unknown> message.